# SELECT statement prints data strangely

Tags: mysql, sql, select, csv

I have a MySQL table called TAG which imports values from a CSV file.

```
mysql> describe TAG;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| TA_BO_ISBN | varchar(14) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TA_Tag     | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I try to view the whole table there appears to be a problem with the ISBN numbers

```
mysql> select * from TAG;
+----------------+----------------+
| TA_BO_ISBN     | TA_Tag         |
+----------------+----------------+
         |794557 | paris
        |1794558 | france
        |1794559 | europe
          |94560 | city
        |1794561 | lonely
```

When I select the ISBN Numbers the result looks good.

```
mysql> select TA_BO_ISBN from TAG;
+----------------+
| TA_BO_ISBN     |
+----------------+
| 978-1741794557 |
| 978-1741794558 |
| 978-1741794559 |
```

Strangely when I select the tags the results look strange again

```
mysql> select TA_TAG from TAG;
+----------------+
| TA_TAG         |
+----------------+
         |
        |
        |
          |
        |
        |
           |
        |
        |
        |
        |
   |untryside
       |r
         |
      |ges
        |
```

This isn't just aesthetic, I have a feeling this is creating problems in my SQL Queries. The import script in case anyone is curious.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'sql/tags.csv'INTO TABLE TAG FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: Can you give us, say, 10 lines of the CSV file?

Comment: Also, could the problem be related to file encoding?

Comment: Here is a link to the first 20 lines of the CSV:http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=764674 Thank you for your help

Comment: `ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`. This is just a long shot in the dark: can you tell us what happens if you say that lines are terminated by '\r\n'? I really see nothing else that could go wrong with this, and even this `\r\n` issue is very unlikely to be the culprit.

Comment: I've tried this, it changes nothing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm out of ideas then, this looks solid to me...

Comment: @user1165379, this is not possible and very weird. My guess is that it is data that might be strange. `SELECT TAG_BO_ISBN` gives correct data but `SELECT *` and `SELECT TA_TAG` gives weird results. So I think it is TA_TAG column that contains corrupt or badly formatted data for few or may be all records. Can you please try running `SELECT * FROM TAG LIMIT 1`? Also, what client are you using - command-line prompt or GUI like phpMyAdmin? I assume you are using former; can you check using phpMyAdmin if it shows similar output? What other columns does the table has?

Comment: Interestingly if you use limit 1 it come out formatted correctly. I've tried with higher limits and it still gives a corrupted result (more corrupted the higher the limit). I'm using putty to SSH into an ubuntu server. I didn't set up the server or install MySQL so can't tell you any more. I'm starting to think that it is putty rather than my database that is creating these problems. The table only has these two columns. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since LIMIT 1 worked fine, I suspect that it is TA_Tag column that might be corrupt in the sense that it might contain new-line characters. And if I'm not wrong the number of new-line characters increase per entry as you move down the table sequentially. The new-line characters are bound to corrupt the output in Putty. If you are looking for the fix, you may create a replica of the table and then using REGEXP regular expressions, replace all "\n" and "\r" characters in TA_Tag in the replica table. If you're satisfied with the end result, repeat the process for the original table

Answer (score 0):

1. Your file contains CRLF (\r\n) as end of line characters.
2. In your query, you tell MySQL to use LF (\n) as end of line character to import the line.
3. Conclusion: the CR (\r) character is imported into the table field instead of being ignored. This creates the visual quirks that you see when you do a select.

To fix this, just change your query to :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'sql/tags.csv'INTO TABLE TAG FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```